# Alea iacta est, plural version?

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, verbs, sentence-translation, plural

I was thinking about the famous Phrase "*alea iacta est*", and I was wondering: how would be the plural version of it?

I thought about

> ALEAS IACTA SUNT

Because *aleas* needs to be in the accusative declination since it's the object and not the subject.

*Sunt* because "they are".

I am just stuck on "*iacta*" which should be conjugated with *sunt* and *aleas*, right?

Should it be *IACENT*?

Comment: "Alea" is not the object, it is the subject. The verb is a perfect passive form (literally, "The die has been cast"). So the plural would be "The dice have been cast", "Aleae iactae sunt".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plural would be *aleae iactae sunt*.

*Alea / aleae* is nominative, because it's the subject of a passive verb-form.

Note that, if you used the accusative case for *alea*, the verb would have to be in the active and its subject would be implicit, or else would have to be a noun or pronoun. So,

*aleam / aleas iecit* means 'he (she, it) threw the di(c)e'. Putting in a discrete subject indicates who did the throwing: *Gaius aleam iecit.*

Answer (score 5):

It does not really make sense to put *"Alea iacta est"* in the plural form. The reason for this is that *alea* does not exactly mean "one dice" or "one die" (as some resources claim), but it in original Latin, [*alea* is the name for the "game of dice" or "set of dice"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3D%231776&redirect=true). As a consequence, using the plural would mean something like "The sets of dice were thrown" which is most probably not the intended meaning.

I found this explanation on the [German wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alea_iacta_est#R.C3.BCck.C3.BCbersetzungen). It says:

> Common incorrect translations are:
>
> - „Aleum iactum est“ (assuming there is a singular *aleum*)
> - „Alea iacta sunt“ (as above, but plural)
>
> The word *alea* in the singular form means the "game of dice" as a whole. Consequently, "Alea iacta sunt" would be a correct plural, but would refer to multiple games (or sets) of dices. In fact, *alea* can be translated in the singular as wells as the plural form. However, in Latin the verb is always in the singular form.

The English wikipedia does not discuss the grammar of the English translation.

---

Also interesting (quoted from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_die_is_cast)):

> The form “the die is cast” is from the Latin iacta ālea est, a grammatically incorrect translation by Suetonius, 121 CE, of the Ancient Greek phrase of Menander ἀνερρίφθω κύβος (anerrhíphthō kúbos), which Caesar quoted in Greek (not Latin). The Greek translates rather as “let the die be cast!”, or “let the game be ventured!”.

Comment: I’ve checked several online Latin dictionaries, and while all of them give *dice game* and/or *game of chance* as possible definitions, all of them give *die* as the primary definition. Moreover, it seems very likely to me that Caesar meant *die* when he said *alea iacta est* simply because one throws dice; one doesn’t throw games. *To throw a game* means to lose in English, but I doubt that the idiom was the same for Romans. So can we get more evidence than an assertion that it’s on the German wikipedia (without even having a link, so we cannot even investigate that article’s sources)?

Comment: @KRyan Thanks for your comment. I've edited my answer to include the link and quote. However, I must say that I don't find it appropriate to immediately downvote my answer. I was just trying to shed some additional light on the subject.

Comment: It’s not additional light if it’s not actually true; including false statements is actually distinctly unhelpful, and that’s literally the definition of something appropriate to downvote. The burden of proof is on you to back up your answer; if you do not do so sufficiently and people think your answer is incorrect, you will and should be downvoted. The wikipedia article you reference does not cite any of its own sources behind its claim, so I still find it unlikely to be true. And the Wiktionary quote, while interesting, neither backs up your primary claim nor really relates to the question.

Comment: The key information is that there are resources stating there is no plural *aleae* because *alea* is a *Plurale tantum* which cannot be put into the grammatical plural. However, for some strange reason, I can find only German quotes for this. Giving up.

Comment: @KRyan I actually agree with this answer. [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dalea) translates *alea* as a "game of dice", and only mentions *tessera* or *talus* as an actual "die." As further evidence, I did a corpus search and did not find a *single* example of *alea* in the plural (surely that is significant!). Can you propose a single example where *alea* can only refer to a physical die, not the game itself?

Comment: @brianpck See, *your comment* is a good answer. *This answer* is not. Because your comment backs up its claims, while the answer does not. I would happily upvote your comment as an answer, whether that be incorporated into this answer or put up as a separate answer.

Comment: @KRyan You're welcome to think so, though he did link to the same L&S entry. The German Wiki entry, though unsourced, is not worthless. I decided to ask the question more explicitly elsewhere: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4499/can-alea-refer-to-a-physical-die-or-only-the-game-of-dice

Comment: Interesting discussion. As a side point, Wiktionary is slightly wrong to translate the Greek ἀνερρίφθω κύβος as “let the die be cast!” or “let the game be ventured!”: ἀνερρίφθω is a perfect imperative, so the literal meaning is "let the die have been cast". Latin can convey this with *alea iacta esto*, which seems to be a variant of the phrase. The Greek κύβος, btw, does mean a single physical die, not a game of dice.

Comment: @TKR Isn't "be cast" the infinitive form of the perfect tense while "have been cast" would actually be present perfect continuous?

Comment: @not2savvy *To be cast* is a present passive infinitive, *to have been cast* is a perfect (aka present perfect) passive infinitive. Present perfect continuous would be *to have been casting*.

Answer (score 0):

I study Latin and Greek: a *lot* of phrases cannot and should not be changed, as they must be used "as is".
No one will try to modify an English like "Beat around the bush" in "bushes".

For grammar, answer from Henry is *clean*.